# SocketChannel how to deal with cutted UTF-8 chars and lines in ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

My system is receiving UTF-8 lines ended by 0x0D 0x0A through a SocketChannel. I read data in a ByteBuffer like this:

```
final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufsize);
final int bytesRead = _mySocket.read(buffer);
```

The buffer is big enough to contain a lot of lines. But I can't have a buffer big enough to contain all lines, lines are processed on the fly.

The buffer can't contain all the lines, so lines may be splitted, a character encoded in more that one byte may also be splitted.

I thought about a solution:

1. process all lines that I can extract by analyzing the ByteBuffer byte by byte (I search 0x0D 0x0A)
2. identify unprocessed bytes
3. store them in a temporary variable
4. clear the ByteBuffer
5. add unprocessed bytes to the ByteBuffer
6. read again the SocketChannel.
7. Repeat this until I have found the line indicating I received all the lines.

Does java or any library already provide this functionnality ?

Thanks for any answer,
Mickaël

Comment: How about any of these 0MQ, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Netty?

Comment: How about BufferedReader.readLine() over a socket? Do you really need to use NIO?

Comment: @EJP Yes I need NIO as my system handles many connections and I can't maintain as much threads as I have connections. The selector is a great functionnality for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use java.util.Scanner, it knows how to deal with SocketChannel and it knows how to read lines

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(_mySocket);
```